# Pandas get the value of column as a condition of next cell of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following table in pandas. the table contains time and the price of the product.

For analysis purposes, I want to have 2 columns which would contain the next time when the product is more than $100 price change & less than $100 price change.

e.g. if I am at cell 09:19 cell the next price more than $100 would be 14:02 & less than $100 would be 11:39 so 14:02 & 11:39 should come in 09:19 row in respective columns.

Same way against cell 09:56, next price more than $100 would be 14:02 & less than $100 would be 12:18 so these 2 values would come in against the row of 09:56.

```
Time    Price_of_product    Time when next price moving by 100 up   Time when next price moving by 100 Down
09:19:00    3252.25     
09:24:00    3259.9      
09:56:00    3199.4      
10:17:00    3222.5      
10:43:00    3191.25     
11:39:00    3143        
12:18:00    2991.7      
13:20:00    3196.35     
13:26:00    3176.1      
13:34:00    3198.85     
13:37:00    3260.75     
14:00:00    3160.85     
14:02:00    3450        
14:19:00    3060.5      
14:30:00    2968.7      
14:31:00    2895.8      
14:52:00    2880.7      
14:53:00    2901.55     
14:55:00    2885.55     
14:57:00    2839.05     
14:58:00    2871.5      
15:00:00    2718.95
```

This is a repetitive task which I have to perform on many datasets hence using pandas/python to help with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should always post some code or at least some logic trials of what you've done so far

Comment: Sure. Since it was not working i deleted will take care in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df['Time_when_next_price_moving_by_100_up'] = np.nan
df['Time_when_next_price_moving_by_100_down'] = np.nan

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    time_up = np.nan
    time_down = np.nan

    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        diff = df.iloc[j]['Price_of_product'] - row['Price_of_product']
        if diff > 100:
            time_up = df.iloc[j]['Time']
        elif diff < -100:
            time_down = df.iloc[j]['Time']
        
        if not pd.isna(time_up) or not pd.isna(time_down):
            break
    
    df.at[i, 'Time_when_next_price_moving_by_100_up'] = time_up
    df.at[i, 'Time_when_next_price_moving_by_100_down'] = time_down
```

Comment: Received following error. ValueError: could not convert string to float: '14:33:00'. Also I am new to python without much experience hence there is some inability.

Comment: add this line at the beginning: `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time`

Comment: hi, in this dataset, it is showing me uptime as 15:29, where as it should have shown 9:36. Time Price Up_Time Down_Time
20-03-24 09:15 1037.3 20-03-24 15:29 
20-03-24 09:30 1080.1 20-03-24 15:29 
20-03-24 09:31 1094.6 20-03-24 15:28 
20-03-24 09:33 1094.95 20-03-24 15:28 
20-03-24 09:34 1119.15 20-03-24 15:24 
20-03-24 09:35 1127.65 20-03-24 15:21 
20-03-24 09:36 1140.3 20-03-24 15:19 
20-03-24 09:37 1130.45 20-03-24 15:21 
20-03-24 09:38 1110.55 20-03-24 15:27 
20-03-24 09:39 1126.7 20-03-24 15:21 
20-03-24 15:28 1205.9  
20-03-24 15:29 1191.15

Comment: I guess it is taking the last time more than $100, I would need first time when diff is >than 100. Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes I've edited the code, in the last if it should be an or, not an and. Try now

Comment: Hi, this works very well, but takes 15-20 mins for 1 dataset. Is there any faster solution to this?